# how to make array javascript variable from php data?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i have case like this. i have hardcode javascript variable like this :

```
 var features = [{
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.702709, 115.224461),
            type: 'info',
            title: 'Pusat Informasi Kota',
            category: 1

        }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.704432, 115.230249),
            type: 'parking',
            title: 'Tempat Parkir Avaliable',
            category: 2
        }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.704442, 115.231239),
            type: 'library',
            title: 'perpustakaan kota',
            category: 3
        }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.702909, 115.230149),
            type: 'parking',
            title: 'ini parkir',
            category: 2
        }];
```

in future, i want to store that data on a table. problem is, i try to make table like image below
[image]

and i was store the data on php array variable $data_location.

do you have idea if i want to change $data_location array into features variable ? i have try to use json_encode but i think i shouldn't work.

```
var features = <?php echo json_encode($data_location);?>;
```

i try to print_r($data_location); this is the result :

```
<html><head>
<title>Styling the Base Map</title>
     </head><body>Array
 (
     [0] =&gt; stdClass Object
    (
        [id] =&gt; 1
        [type] =&gt; info
        [category] =&gt; 1
        [title_info] =&gt; Pusat Informasi Kota'
        [name] =&gt; Pusat Informasi Kota'
        [lat] =&gt; -8.70271
        [long] =&gt; 115.224
    )

[1] =&gt; stdClass Object
    (
        [id] =&gt; 2
        [type] =&gt; parking
        [category] =&gt; 2
        [title_info] =&gt; Tempat Parkir Avaliable
        [name] =&gt; parkir 1
        [lat] =&gt; -8.70443
        [long] =&gt; 115.23
    )

[2] =&gt; stdClass Object
    (
        [id] =&gt; 3
        [type] =&gt; library
        [category] =&gt; 3
        [title_info] =&gt; perpustakaan kota
        [name] =&gt; Perpus 1
        [lat] =&gt; -8.70444
        [long] =&gt; 115.231
    )

    )
    </body></html>
```

do you have any suggestion?

-thank you in advance-

Comment: It looks like you are doing something wrong when declaring your array of php objects. Posting that code would probably help solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all fetch all the records from database and create a new php array from the results according to your requirement and then json_encode that array in your script...

You can do something like this, I hope that you can understand this code easily..

```
<?php 
$data_locations =array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM your_table');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $arr['position'] =  'new google.maps.LatLng('.$row['lat'].' , '.$row['long'].')';
    $arr['type'] = $row['type'];
    $arr['title'] = $row['title_info'];
    $arr['category'] = $row['category'];
    $data_locations[] = $arr;
}
?>
```

And in your script json encode `$data_locations` array..

```
<script>
var features = <?php echo json_encode($data_locations);?>;
</script>
```

Comment: wait, i will try first :). thanks for your response Manjeet :)

Comment: Hi Manjeet, i used codeigniter. i try to use this code, is it right? <?php
                foreach($data_location as $row){

    $arr['position'] =  'new google.maps.LatLng('.$row->lat.' , '.$row->long.')';
    $arr['type'] = $row->type;
    $arr['title'] = $row->title_info;
    $arr['category'] = $row->category;
    $data_locations[] = $arr;

                }

               
        ?>

Comment: is your variable `$data_location` contains the query result in it, If yes then you can use this .. @IIMNURDIANSYAH

Comment: yes, it contains query result.  i try another way, i code like this but my marker still not show : var features = [
<?php foreach ($data_lokasi as $row) {?>
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row->lat; ?>,<?php echo $row->long; ?> ),
                   type: <?php echo "'".$row->type."'"; ?>,
                title: <?php echo "'".$row->title_info."'"; ?>,
            },

<?php }?>];  here is complete code on pastebin : http://pastebin.com/2mFERHkA

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH you are declaring var features directly with php code, this will not work, first of all make an php array and then assign it to js variable with json encode, then it will work..

Comment: i know the problem, why in my database show longitude value 115.224 but when i trace it using consol.log, the output is 115.223999999999999993

Comment: i have try your code and show an error,  i saw in firebug that array position read as a string, not a function. so  $arr['position'] =  'new google.maps.LatLng('.$row['lat'].' , '.$row['long'].')'; will return a string an google maps marker will not work.

Comment: then you can use `$arr['lat'] =  $row['lat'];` and `$arr['long'] =  $row['long'];` then in script use `position: new google.maps.LatLng(feature.lat,feature.long)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113980/discussion-between-iim-nur-diansyah-and-manjeet-barnala).

Comment: no, thanks it is work (y). but i have new problem now. my check box doesn't work after i get marker data from table. i think the problem is marker category.....

Comment: where you are using checkbox ??

Comment: i want to show marker by category. but now i found the problem. it because triple ===. when i used double ==, it works perfect. by the way, what is different between === and == ????

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH `==` only compares values and `===` compares values and type of variable

Comment: wooww. thankyou for your explain. btw, what is yout facebook account? or email maybe, i want learn a lot with you.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a JSON string into a JavaScript object by using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Something like
`var features = JSON.parse( <?php echo json_encode($data_location);?> );` 
may work, if the output of `echo json_encode($data_location)` is valid JSON.